# How to initialize a QOpenGLContext on OS X to use OpenGL version 3.3?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opengl

I’m running OS X 10.9.4 and Qt 5.3.1. I need to create a QOpenGLContext that uses Open GL 3.3. My system reports 100% compatibility with OpenGL 3.3, however I am getting a context that supports 2.1 only. As well, calling versionFunctions() returns 0.

What is the correct modification to, say, the OpenGL Window Example (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtgui-openglwindow-example.html) that makes it possible to use OpenGL 3.3? I’ve tried to set the desired version on the QSurfaceFormat, but I haven’t been able to make it work on this system (on Windows, I get a context with OpenGL version that matches the highest supported by that system — by default.)

Comment: OSX only supports Core contexts for GL > 2.1.  Are you creating a Core context?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply - I am new to Qt but I'm guessing that I am creating a Core context. I'm working off of the OpenGL Window Example. For now, I just need an OpenGL 3.3 main window that draws directly through gl calls and responds to keyboard/mouse events through Qt. Is there a better example to start off of?

Answer (score 0):

My question got answered, the problem is that while I was calling QSurfaceFormat::setVersion(3,3) it is also required to call QSurfaceFormat::setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile) before passing the resulting QSurfaceFormat to setFormat.